# Weighted clustering in ML.net without training

Tags: cluster-analysis, ml.net

I'm looking to see if I can use ML.net to cluster a one-off set of weighted points that I don't have any training data for. I just need the points divided into a specified number of clusters, with each weighted cluster size being with a specified range.

Is that something ML.net can do? If so, how?

Comment: Looking for the exact same thing, did you have any progress? Thanks in advance.